# How to change process state from sleep to running in linux?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, memory

I have a python program which needs to scan some large log files to extract useful information.

In this program, to better utilize computing resource of sever (which runs ubuntu 12.04 LTS and has 64 cores and 96 GB memory), **I create a process pool with size = 10 and apply sever jobs to these pool workers.** Each job reads from several large files(about 50 GB each, 20 files in total) by using `file.readlines()`, and then analyze them line by line to find useful information and save the results in a dictionary. After all files are scanned and analyzed, the result dictionary is wrote to the disk. Besides, there is no explicit call of `gc.collect()` in the whole script.

I started this program on server using root account and these processes works fine at first: each process of this program will occupies about 3.8 GB memory, so there is 40 GB in total

After a few hours, **some other user starts another memory-consuming program (also use root account), which aggressively uses almost all the memory (99% of total memory), and later this program is interrupted by `CTRL-Z` and killed by using `killall -9 process_name`**

However, after this, I have found that the **process state of most of my poolworkers have been changed to S, the CPU usage of these sleep process is decreased to 0.** According to man `top`:

```
 The status of the task which can be one of:
 'D' = uninterruptible sleep,
 'R' = running,
 'S' = sleeping,
 'T' = traced or stopped,
 'Z' = zombie
```

I used ps -axl command to check the name of the kernel function where the process is sleeping, and **it turns out to these poolworker processes sleep on `_fastMutex`.**

This situation lasts for a long time(The process state is still S now) and I don't want to restart my process to scan all the files again, **how can I change these process from state Sleep to Running ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sleeping state indicates that they are waiting for something; the way to wake them up is to satisfy whatever condition it is they wait for (the mutex is probably the mechanism of waiting, not the condition itself). The references to memory consumption suggest the possibility that some processes are at least partially paged out, in which case they would be waiting for the swapper; however, that results in uninterruptible sleep D, not S.

System calls that are in interruptible sleep can also be interrupted by signals, such as alarm, terminate, stop, or continue. Most signals cause the program to abort, however. The two that are (usually) safe, continue and ignore, don't change program flow; so it would just go back to sleep on the same condition again.

Most likely, the reason your processes are in S is that they're genuinely waiting for outside input. Since all we know of your program is that it loads a lot of data, I can't tell you where that happens.

As for how you've described your program: "Each job reads from several large files ... using file.readlines(), and then analyze them line by line". It's highly unlikely this is an efficient way to do it; if you're only scanning line by line in one sweep, it's better to iterate on the file objects in the first place (getting one line at a time). If you're reading text lines in a random order, [linecache](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) is your friend. Using [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) you could avoid copying the data from the disk buffers. Which is the best fit depends on the structure of your data and algorithm.

By "state of most of my poolworkers have been changed to S" I suspect that the *other* workers are what's interesting. Perhaps the sleeping ones are just waiting for the ones that are paged out to return.